# Wrap Observable from static method for error handling

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm using RxJS for some file processing -- specifically I'm reading from a file, doing some processing, and writing to another file. The [`fromEvent`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromEvent) static Observable method seems perfect for this since I can use it to hook into the stream events.

```
const reader = createReadStream(inputFile);
const writer = createWriteStream(outputFile);

fromEvent(reader, 'readable').pipe(
  map(() => reader.read()),
  processString(),
  tap(chunk => writer.write(chunk)),
  takeUntil(fromEvent(reader, 'close'))
).subscribe({
  error(err) { console.error(err); },
  complete() { console.log('done'); },
})
```

This works perfectly, but the problem is that if there is an error outside of the observable stream (for example `inputFile` does not exist) I can't catch it using the Observables. I would have to handle it separately.

To get around this, I've wrapped `fromEvent` creation in an observable I don't really use:

```
of(1).pipe(
  switchMap(() =>
    reader = ...
    writer = ...
    return fromEvent(...)
```

This works, but it feels strange to create an Observable like this to wrap functionality for error handling. Is there a preferred way to perform some set up an Observable and handle errors during the setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [`defer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-defer):

```
import { defer } from 'rxjs/observable/defer';

const obs = defer(() => {
  const reader = ...
  const writer = ...
  return fromEvent(...);
});
```

`defer` takes a factory function that returns an observable. The factory function will be called when a subscription is made to the observable returned from the call to `defer`.

If an error occurs in the factory function, it will be emitted via an `error` notification in the observable stream.